# Connect C# to Cassandra on Azure VM

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, cassandra

I'm using Azure cloud and want to connect C# project with Cassandra on a virtual machine. I've installed the Cassandra VM with the provided template, but I can't get it to work. I can connect to the VM via SSH, but not with C# application. I'm using [csharp-driver](https://github.com/datastax/csharp-driver) (v3.1.0) to interact with Cassandra. To connect, I'm doing this:

```
var cluster = Cassandra.Cluster.Builder()
                               .AddContactPoint("My_Azure_Cassandra_VM_public_IP")
                               .WithPort(9042)
                               .Build();
cluster.Connect();
```

The last line throws an exception:

> Cassandra.NoHostAvailableException: 'None of the hosts tried for query
>   are available (tried: My_Azure_Cassandra_VM_public_IP:9042)'

So I connected to the VM via SSH and try to find a solution.

Cassandra is installed:

```
> sudo cassandra -R -v
3.11.0
```

But it's not running:

```
> cqlsh
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': AuthenticationFailed('Remote end requires authentication.',)})
```

So I tried to run it, but I get the following:

```
> service cassandra start
cassandra: unrecognized service
```

So, what is the next step? I'm out of ideas (and useful Google search results), I've double checked the settings in **cassandra.yaml** and everything seems OK. The Azures' Network security group seems fine too:

> PRIORITY | NAME | SOURCE | DESTINATION | SERVICE | ACTION
>
> 1010 | Cassandra | Any | Any | Cassandra (TCP/9042) | Allow
>
> 1020 | default-allow-ssh | Any | Any | SSH (TCP/22) | Allow

Comment: Linux VM:
`Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS`;
`netstat -ant|grep 9042`:
`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9042            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

Comment: Your cqlsh error doesn't mean that Cassandra is not running.  It means that you're not providing cqlsh with a valid username/password.  Also, if you need to give cqlsh the IP address that Cassandra is listening for requests on.  Check your values for `listen_address` and/or `rpc_address`.  If those are set to 127.0.0.1/localhost, then you won't be able to connect remotely (although cqlsh should work).

Comment: The `listen_address` and `rpc_address` are set correctly. Which credentials do I need to use for cqlsh? I only provided VM credentials when creating the VM. That's why I thought it must be some other problem with the cqlsh.

Comment: When you turn on auth, it creates a default user of cassandra/cassandra.  `cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra`.  Assuming of course that your node accepts requests on 127.0.0.1.  Otherwise you'll need to provide your IP/host as well.

Comment: `cqlsh My_Azure_Cassandra_VM_public_IP 9042 -u cassandra -p cassandra`:
`Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'My_Azure_Cassandra_VM_public_IP': OperationTimedOut('errors=Timed out creating connection (5 seconds), last_host=None',)})`

Comment: Try it without your public_IP.

Comment: I did. Same error.

Comment: `ps -ef | grep cassandra`  Is it running?

Comment: I seems so, I get a big output.

Comment: Could you check cassandra logs if is there any error during startup? Did you connect with cqlsh inside azure vm? If thats the case, the issue might be a blocked port.

Comment: Now I've also tried to connect inside azure VM, istead from my PC, and I get: `Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'My_Azure_Cassandra_VM_public_IP': AuthenticationFailed('Failed to authenticate to My_Azure_Cassandra_VM_public_IP: Error from server: code=0100 [Bad credentials] message="Provided username My_username and/or password are incorrect"',)})`. And about the logs - I can't seem to find them on the Azure VM.

Comment: Any suggestions?